# How to get current profile path?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When vscode launched with `--profile-temp` or `--profile=myprofile`, within an extension code how to get the path where all the data of the profile is stored?

For default profile I use:

```
const dir = (process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE ? process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE + "/user-data" : process.env.APPDATA + "/Code") + "/User/";
```

It seems to work on portable and installed version of vscode, but when profile is used, the path is:

```
const dir = (process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE ? process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE + "/user-data" : process.env.APPDATA + "/Code") + "/User/Profiles/%profilefoldername%/"
```

where `%profilefoldername%` is some random name.

Comment: When that value is available it should be mentioned here: [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

Comment: And how would one access these values within javascript of the extension, not within .json?

Comment: added the tag `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

My current method is to change a global value of one of the preferences (type = "string") to a unique `id` and search for updated `settings.json` with that `id`
This method uses `jsonc-parser` package:

```
npm install jsonc-parser
```

```js
import { parse } from "jsonc-parser";
const profileDir = new Promise(resolve => {
  let profileDir;
  const extensionPrefScope = "myExtension", //myExtension.mySetting
    extensionPrefName = "mySetting",
    prefs = workspace.getConfiguration(extensionPrefScope),
    pref = prefs.inspect(extensionPrefName), //get info about the setting
    prefValue = pref.globalValue !== undefined ? pref.globalValue.replace(/ ?-profileDirID[\d.]+$/, "") : pref.globalValue,
    //generate ID, in some rare circumstances previous ID could still be present, try remove it
    id = (prefValue ? prefValue + " " : "") + "-profileDirID." + new Date().getTime() + performance.now(),
    dir = ((process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE ? process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE + "/user-data" : {
        windows: process.env.APPDATA + "/Code",
        macos: process.env.HOME + "/Library/Application Support/Code",
        linux: process.env.HOME + "/config/Code"
      }[{darwin: "macos", win32: "windows" }[process.platform]||"linux"]) + "/User/")
      .replace(/\//g, process.platform == "win32" ? "\\" : "/"),
    watcher = workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(new RelativePattern(dir, "**/settings.json")),
    watcherHandler = uri => {
      if (profileDir)
        return;

      fs.readFile(uri.fsPath, (err, data) => {
        if (profileDir)
          return;

        const json = parse(data.toString());
        if (json[pref.key] !== id )
          return;

        profileDir = uri.fsPath.replace(/[^\\/]+$/, "");
        watcher.dispose();
        reset();
      });
    },
    reset = () => {
      console.log(id);
      clearTimeout(resetTimer);
      prefs.update(extensionPrefName, prefValue, true);
      resolve(profileDir || dir);
    };
  watcher.onDidChange(watcherHandler);
  watcher.onDidCreate(watcherHandler);
  prefs.update(extensionPrefName, id, true);
  const resetTimer = setTimeout(reset, 2000);
});

profileDir.then(console.log);
```

replace `myExtension` and `mySetting` with your setting scope/name.
This method has fail-safe, if `setting.json` is not found after 2 seconds, it restores setting to original value and returns a "generic" path.

*Only tested on Windows*